# How to change equations color in MathJax

Tags: javascript, css, mathjax

I'm using the following snippet to display equations on my blog

```
<script src='http://www.mathjax.org/mathjax/MathJax.js' type='text/javascript'> 
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]}
  });
</script>
```

and I would like to change equations color to white because my background is somewhat dark, how can this be done?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, since my question dates from 2 years, I remember that I found a solution and I don't remember which it is. I suspect that it was the solution you give. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
.MathJax_Display {
  color: #FFF !important;
}
```

It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Equations should inherit styles from ancestor elements, just like any normal element. 
You could try something like the following:

```
<head>
 <style>.equation { color: white; }</style>
</head>
<body>
 <span class="equation">$ax^2+bx+c$</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks,the class is .MathJax, and I will not change the color finally, because the color of some symbols is always black (because they are images) so I will change the background it will be more esthetic.