# How do you change the color of an equation containing images in mathjax?

Tags: mathjax

I noticed that math.SE uses mathjax and has equations in a blue color.

[image: example of equation in color]
Notice how the infinity sign is colored aswell.

However one would expect this to remain black because - as mentioned here: [How to change equations color in MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949100/how-to-change-equations-color-in-mathjax) - those symbols are in fact images who's color is not effected. Like so:
[image: example of equation in color, but with images not being colored]

So, how do they change the color of those images as well? I thought it was impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax should use image mode only in a few rare cases these days.  The main one is when you use Firefox to view local files (via a `file://` url) and MathJax is not in the same directory as the HTML file being viewed.  In this case, Firefox's same-origin policy considers MathJax to be in a separate domain, and so fails to be able to access the web-based fonts since it considers that to be cross-domain access.  So MathJax uses image fonts as a fallback because it can't use web-based fonts.  I'm guessing that is what is happening for you.

Math.SE doesn't have that problem since it is not a `file://` url and Firefox doesn't have trouble recognizing what domain is what, so you get actual web-based fonts and not images and they can be colored properly (unlike the images).  Math.SE doesn't have to do anything special to make that happen, and you are *not* seeing colored images, but actual fonts.  That is the difference from your uncolored examples.

The solution for the Firefox local-file problem is to install the [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/), or MathJax's own OTF fonts, in your system's fonts folder.  You can find the MathJax fonts in the `MathaJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf` directory of the MathJax distribution that you have installed locally.  If these are available as actual fonts on your system, MathJax won't have to use web-based versions, and so it can avoid the Firefox issue with the same-origin policy.  This will also speed up any page using MathJax anywhere (like Math.SE) since it won't have to download the fonts over the web.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on "in your system's fonts folder"? What do you mean by that and will it work if you are working with subdomains?

Comment: I'm talking about installing the fonts on the computer where you are running your browser.  You need to install the fonts as system fonts in whatever why that works for your OS.  On Windows, you can drag the fonts to the Fonts folder (you open it through the control panel).  On MacOS you can move the fonts to your `~/Library/Fonts` directory.  On unix, I think you put them in `~/.fonts`.  I am working under the assumption that you are developing web pages locally (using `file://` URLs) using Firefox.  If that's not the case, can you say more about your setup?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. No, I am not working locally. You can see an example of my working mathJax here: http://lrn2college.com/ and and example of a subdomainpage here: http://testsubdom.lrn2college.com/. This works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: OK, this is still Firefox's cross-domain restrictions during the font loading, which is preventing MathJax from accessing the web-based fonts, so it times out waiting for them and falls back on image fonts.  Local files is the most common way to run into that, but subdomains is another.  You need to set the access control on your main server (lrn2college.com) to allow cross domain access to the fonts.  See [the documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/installation.html#notes-about-shared-installations) for how to do that.

Comment: That worked perfectly. This will only give access to my fonts and so in no case be a securityissue right?

Comment: If you have put the .htaccess file in the fonts directory, it will only affect that one directly, and only files that end with those extensions.  You it is possible for others to load the fonts from their websites (if you used the `*` domain), but with the MathJax CDN, I don't see any reason for someone to do that.  So I think you are pretty secure.